# Ну(,) надо же-с

Tags: запятые

Нужна запятая? Я думаю, что нет таки.

> Ну(,) надо же.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Зачем это делать? **Ну, надо же*** — пауза (функция междометия); первое значение.

*Зачем это делать? **Ну надо же*** — нет паузы (функция частицы); первое значение.

***Ну надо же (= «вот это да»)*** — второе значение (функция частицы); без паузы.

Вряд ли во втором значении может быть какая-то пауза. Запятую во втором значении не ставим.